# entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate and I have this error.

```
Error SQL query:
  --
  -- Dumping data for table `client`
  --
 INSERT INTO `client` (`client_id`, `school_id`, `firstname`, `middlename`, `lastname`, `type`, `department`, `contact`, `date`)
 VALUES (1, 21200547, 'Rolyn Jasper', 'C.', 'Demerin', 'Student', 'ICT', '09989781348', '2015-11-10 14:43:00'),
        (2, 23534598, 'Ludevic', 'A.', 'Servilla', 'Student', 'ICT', '09345453453', '2015-11-20 13:35:55');
```

MySQL said:

> Documentation  #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

These are my databases. (

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump -- version 4.0.4 -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net -- -- Host: localhost -- Generation Time: Dec 09, 2015 at 04:49 AM -- Server version: 5.6.12-log -- PHP Version: 5.4.12  SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; SET time_zone = "+00:00";   /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */; /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */; /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */; /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;  -- -- Database: `rms` -- CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `rms` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci; USE `rms`;  -- --------------------------------------------------------
 --
 -- Table structure for table `client`
 --
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client` (
   `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `school_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `firstname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `middlename` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `department` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `contact` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `date` datetime NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
  -- -- Dumping data for table `client`
  --
  INSERT INTO `client` (`client_id`, `school_id`, `firstname`, `middlename`, `lastname`, `type`, `department`, `contact`, `date`)
  VALUES (1, 21200547, 'Rolyn Jasper', 'C.', 'Demerin', 'Student', 'ICT', '09989781348', '2015-11-10 14:43:00'),
         (2, 23534598, 'Ludevic', 'A.', 'Servilla', 'Student', 'ICT', '09345453453', '2015-11-20 13:35:55');
  -- --------------------------------------------------------
  -- -- Table structure for table `history` --  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `history` (   `history_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `date` datetime NOT NULL,   `action` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `data` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`history_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=82 ;  -- -- Dumping data for table `history` --  INSERT INTO `history` (`history_id`, `date`, `action`, `data`) VALUES (1, '2015-11-10 14:01:56', 'Add User', ' John Doe'), (2, '2015-11-10 14:02:41', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (3, '2015-11-10 14:03:05', 'Add User', 'John Doe'), (4, '2015-11-10 14:04:16', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (5, '2015-11-10 14:04:49', 'Login', 'Jane Doe'), (6, '2015-11-10 14:04:56', 'Logout', 'Jane Doe'), (7, '2015-11-10 14:05:09', 'Login', 'Jane Doe'), (8, '2015-11-10 14:05:31', 'Add User', 'Jane Doe'), (9, '2015-11-10 14:41:30', 'Add Client', 'John Doe'), (10, '2015-11-10 14:41:34', 'Add Client', 'John Doe'), (11, '2015-11-10 14:43:00', 'Add Client', 'John Doe'), (12, '2015-11-10 14:45:34', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (13, '2015-11-17 12:36:35', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (14, '2015-11-17 12:50:47', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (15, '2015-11-17 12:50:51', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (16, '2015-11-17 13:35:08', 'Add Item', 'John Doe'), (17, '2015-11-18 15:05:00', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (18, '2015-11-18 15:44:13', 'Add Item', 'John Doe'), (19, '2015-11-18 16:16:45', 'Edit Item Details', 'John Doe'), (20, '2015-11-18 16:17:04', 'Edit Item Details', 'John Doe'), (21, '2015-11-18 16:27:13', 'Add Item', 'John Doe'), (22, '2015-11-18 16:27:20', 'Delete Item', ' '), (23, '2015-11-18 16:27:44', 'Add Item', 'John Doe'), (24, '2015-11-18 16:30:25', 'Delete Item', ' '), (25, '2015-11-18 16:34:10', 'Add Item', 'John Doe'), (26, '2015-11-18 16:34:57', 'Delete Item', 'John Doe'), (27, '2015-11-18 16:36:05', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (28, '2015-11-18 16:36:47', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (29, '2015-11-18 16:37:15', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (30, '2015-11-20 10:37:19', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (31, '2015-11-20 13:24:38', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (32, '2015-11-20 13:25:35', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (33, '2015-11-20 13:31:44', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (34, '2015-11-20 13:32:35', 'Add User', 'John Doe'), (35, '2015-11-20 13:35:55', 'Add Client', 'John Doe'), (36, '2015-11-20 13:37:29', 'Add Item', 'John Doe'), (37, '2015-11-21 18:32:01', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (38, '2015-11-21 18:34:06', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (39, '2015-11-21 18:34:11', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (40, '2015-11-21 18:37:01', 'Add Item', 'John Doe'), (41, '2015-11-21 22:39:38', 'Edit Client Details', 'John Doe'), (42, '2015-11-21 22:40:21', 'Edit Client Details', 'John Doe'), (43, '2015-11-21 22:40:41', 'Edit Client Details', 'John Doe'), (44, '2015-11-21 22:46:41', 'Add Client', 'John Doe'), (45, '2015-11-21 22:47:27', 'Delete Client', 'John Doe'), (46, '2015-11-21 22:48:02', 'Delete Client', 'John Doe'), (47, '2015-11-21 22:48:30', 'Add Client', 'John Doe'), (48, '2015-11-21 22:48:52', 'Delete Client', 'John Doe'), (49, '2015-11-21 23:12:05', 'Edit User Details', 'John Doe'), (50, '2015-11-21 23:16:23', 'Delete User', 'John Doe'), (51, '2015-11-21 23:16:31', 'Delete User', 'John Doe'), (52, '2015-11-21 23:16:40', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (53, '2015-11-21 23:17:28', 'Login', 'Jane Doe'), (54, '2015-11-21 23:18:51', 'Logout', 'Jane Doe'), (55, '2015-11-22 23:03:55', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (56, '2015-11-23 00:09:10', 'Edit Client Details', 'John Doe'), (57, '2015-11-23 00:09:50', 'Edit Client Details', 'John Doe'), (58, '2015-11-23 00:10:01', 'Edit Client Details', 'John Doe'), (59, '2015-11-23 00:15:53', 'Edit User Details', 'John Doe'), (60, '2015-11-23 00:16:03', 'Edit User Details', 'John Doe'), (61, '2015-11-23 00:17:51', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (62, '2015-11-23 00:17:56', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (63, '2015-11-23 00:18:40', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (64, '2015-11-23 00:24:12', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (65, '2015-11-23 07:59:10', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (66, '2015-11-23 08:10:45', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (67, '2015-11-23 08:43:58', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (68, '2015-11-23 08:50:00', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (69, '2015-11-23 11:36:30', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (70, '2015-11-23 12:14:46', 'Logout', 'Jane Doe'), (71, '2015-11-23 12:14:50', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (72, '2015-11-23 13:18:53', 'Logout', ' '), (73, '2015-11-23 13:18:56', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (74, '2015-11-23 13:22:42', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (75, '2015-11-23 13:23:02', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (76, '2015-12-01 16:25:51', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (77, '2015-12-01 18:14:18', 'Logout', 'John Doe'), (78, '2015-12-01 22:27:44', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (79, '2015-12-02 01:06:56', 'Logout', 'Jane Doe'), (80, '2015-12-02 15:27:04', 'Login', 'John Doe'), (81, '2015-12-04 16:24:19', 'Login', 'John Doe');  -- --------------------------------------------------------  -- -- Table structure for table `item` --  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (   `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `item_id_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `item_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `item_brand` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `item_description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `item_qty` int(11) NOT NULL,   `item_price` int(11) NOT NULL,   `item_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `date` datetime NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;  -- -- Dumping data for table `item` --  INSERT INTO `item` (`item_id`, `item_id_id`, `item_name`, `item_brand`, `item_description`, `item_qty`, `item_price`, `item_type`, `date`) VALUES (1, 21002340, 'Xtyle Optical Mouse', 'Mac', 'Optical Mouse', 60, 200, 'Consumable', '2015-11-17 13:35:08'), (2, 23508020, 'USB Cord', 'Samsung', 'USB Cord 3.0', 35, 180, 'Non-Consumable', '2015-11-18 15:44:13'), (3, 82458334, 'Mouse Pad', 'Acer', 'Mouse Pad Duo', 46, 50, 'Non-Consumable', '2015-11-20 13:37:30');  -- --------------------------------------------------------  -- -- Table structure for table `release_details` --  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `release_details` (   `release_details_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `release_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `release_status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `date_return` datetime NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`release_details_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;  -- --------------------------------------------------------  -- -- Table structure for table `tbl_release` --  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_release` (   `release_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `date_borrow` datetime NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`release_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;  -- --------------------------------------------------------  -- -- Table structure for table `transaction_history` --  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transaction_history` (   `transaction_history_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `action` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `release_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `admin_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_history_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;  -- -- Dumping data for table `transaction_history` --  INSERT INTO `transaction_history` (`transaction_history_id`, `item_id`, `action`, `client_id`, `release_id`, `admin_name`, `date_added`) VALUES (1, 2, 'Borrowing Item', 2, 1, 'Jane Doe', '2015-12-02 00:23:33'), (2, 1, 'Borrowing Item', 2, 1, 'Jane Doe', '2015-12-02 00:23:34'), (3, 3, 'Borrowing Item', 1, 2, 'Jane Doe', '2015-12-02 00:30:13'), (4, 2, 'Borrowing Item', 1, 2, 'Jane Doe', '2015-12-02 00:30:13'), (5, 1, 'Borrowing Item', 1, 2, 'Jane Doe', '2015-12-02 00:30:14'), (6, 3, 'Borrowing Item', 2, 3, 'John Doe', '2015-12-02 15:28:04'), (7, 2, 'Borrowing Item', 2, 3, 'John Doe', '2015-12-02 15:28:04'), (8, 1, 'Borrowing Item', 2, 3, 'John Doe', '2015-12-02 15:28:04'), (9, 3, 'Borrowing Item', 1, 4, 'John Doe', '2015-12-04 16:58:09');  -- --------------------------------------------------------  -- -- Table structure for table `user` --  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `firstname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `middlename` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `user_added` datetime NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;  -- -- Dumping data for table `user` --  INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`, `firstname`, `middlename`, `lastname`, `username`, `password`, `user_added`) VALUES (1, 'John', 'M.', 'Doe', 'admin', 'admin', '2015-11-10 14:01:56'), (2, 'Jane', 'M.', 'Doe', 'admin', 'jane', '2015-11-10 14:03:05');  /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */; /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */; /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all: you already have a record with `client_id` `1` in your `client` table, so it cannot be inserted.